# C++, Is it possible / how would you define a class constructor that calls a function in the .h & .cpp source files

Tags: c++, constructor

Still fresh on C++ so I apologize if this is a stupid question,

I'm trying to declare a class in a header file that calls a initialization function while passing the arguments from the constructor.

I figure I'm doing a lot wrong, so any and all code corrections / practices are welcome.

*Main.cpp:*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Main.h"

void Class::_init(int i)
{
    this->initValue = i;
}

//not sure if this is the correct syntax
Class::Class(int i)
{
    //throws an error with "truple" ~ Not Sure What That Means
    this->_init(i);
}
```

*Main.h:*

```cpp
#pragma once

class Class
{
    //note this is simplifying the class, but keeps the concept
private:
    int initValue;

    void _init(int i);
public:
    Class(int i);
};
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message. The code you posted is correct - the error is somewhere else. Please post a [mre].

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ygVBSYk9Ba2l4CB1

Comment: As a side node: avoid names starting with an underscore, as these are reserved for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

So I mistook the error I was getting for an issue concerning the constructor arguments not being able to be incorporated, turns out I just needed to assign default values to said arguments which I hadn't thought of doing.

Error Was: "no appropriate default constructor available" : C2512

```cpp
//.h
class Class {
public:
    //sets default value for argument
    Class(Object obj = Object(*Constructor Argument*));
}
```

```cpp
//.cpp
Class::Class(Object obj) {
    //code
}
```